# Postgres client Application has lot of idle connections with empty query or `DISCARD ALL`

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds-proxy

We use Postgres in AWS RDS with RDS proxy.

Our Application is micro services with database per service model. Couple of services(one node JS and another one is Java Spring boot) holds idle connections with query field is either empty or `DISCARD ALL`, What does that mean ?

Also the query_start keeps changing and has recent time always.

Is it due to RDS Proxy? It looks like blocking the connections.

[image]

Comment: " It looks like blocking the connections."  What does that mean?  Nothing you show indicates anything is blocking anything else.

Comment: When a service hold these connections other service is deprived for connection. One more thing I forgot to mention here, query_start is keeps changing  and always have recent time.

Comment: You seem to be looking at a regular connection pool. Perhaps the pool size is larger than it should be.